# Get value of previous element when checkbox is checked jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I doing that get the value of html element when user check on checkbox using jquery. I am not using id because this is repeating row feature

I am trying this

```js
$(document).on('click', '.row_checkbox ', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    console.log("checked");
    var unit_price = $(this).parent().prev().children().val();
    console.log(unit_price);
  } else {

  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="form-control row_price" name="order_innerprice[]">
    </td>
    <td>
      <label class="checkbox checkbox-custom-alt">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control row_checkbox" name="order_checkbox[]"><i></i>
     </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I've reformatted your code, so that you clearly see that `input`'s `parent()` is the `label`.   So there's no `prev` or `children`.   Change `$(this).parent()` to `$(this).closest("td")`

Comment: I already solve my problem

Comment: Using `.parent().parent()` is also a bad idea, for the same reason - if you change the layout in the future, eg you choose to not use a label wrapper and put the label as a sibling of your input, your code will again fail.

Comment: Your code is not working

Comment: What code?  The edit in the question? That's *your* code.  My suggested edit [work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/7y8kpb2a/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this by try this one

```
$(document).on('click','.row_checkbox ',function(){
    if (this.checked){
        console.log("checked");
    var unit_price  =  $(this).parent().parent().prev().children().val();
    console.log(unit_price);
} else {
    
}
    
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).